# After the IDEA was imported into the project, the yml file was not recognized

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project-structure

When I was learning springboot, I encountered the following problems:
After the idea is imported into the project, the yml file is not recognized.Each time file type is configured, there is still no icon for springboot.When the IDEA is opened again, the yml file is still not recognized. The filetype configured previously is invalid and needs to be configured again.

**Note:**

1. Clone from Github
2. has tried many times, still no springboot icon appears
3. Yml file cannot be added to the project structure. When you want to add yml file, it displays :"no configuration files matching pattern 'application' found ".

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate? Is the file located under the **resource** directory? Add screenshots showing the problem.

Comment: @Andrey Sorry, I didn't describe the problem clearly.
I used IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and I confirm that the file is in the resource directory.
Also sorry, I can't upload the picture now.